# Using an Openmote-B ADC

Tags: c, contiki, adc, contiki-ng, contiki-process

I'm working on signal acquisition and transmission using Openmote-B. I have an analogue signal from a sensor, that is to be transmitted using an openmote. Is it possible to directly feed the analog data to the Openmote? How can I use the inbuild ADC in CC2538 for this purpose?
Thank You.

I'm new to this Communication side. I have gone through the data sheets and other available sources about Openmote-B. I'm expecting to know how I can use the available ADC in the SoC and get resources related with it.